# Is Curse Bringer + Divine Smite + Wrathful Smite + Greenflame Blade RAW, RAI or Neither?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, multi-classing, paladin, hexblade

Warlock Hexblade (3), Paladin (x)

Boon: Pact of the Blade

Eldritch Invocations: Curse Bringer.
Need minimum 5 lvls

Turn 1.1 Hexblade curse (bonus action)

Turn 2.1 (bonus action) Wrathful Smite

Turn 2.2 (normal action) Greenflame Blade

If melee hit spend 1 spell slot for Curse Bringer (no action) and 1 for Divine Smite (no action)

Comment: Ah I have now found it from [this Unearthed Arcana](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/warlock-and-wizard) ([direct link](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_wizrd_wrlck_uav2_i48nf.pdf))

Comment: Yes that is right. And the duplicate suggestion answer my question. Interesting I didn't find it even though I have been researching all day.

Comment: And I felt I needed to add the numbers because I use them in my arguments for and against allowing it to stack

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Arguments for/against generally shouldn't be part of the question - and in this case, whether the spells/features "should" stack is an opinion-based question that's entirely separate from the question of whether they *do* stack based on the rules (and designer intent) - so arguments for/against it are irrelevant to your primary question of whether they do. It's best to keep your question straightforward and focused on your primary question, rather than diverging into tangents.

Comment: Then I will edit the question thereafter :)

Comment: Some general related questions: "[Are you allowed to stack Divine Smite and Eldritch Smite on the same attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110110)" and "[Is my Paladin stacking Smite spells correctly?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109179)" and "[Can I combine Haste, Green Flame Blade, Divine Smite, and Thunderous Smite like this?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102932)" and "[Can I use Booming Blade and Wrathful Smite in the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102749)"